# ESP8266 Client Connection Failure

Tags: http, arduino, client, esp8266

I am having issues sending HTTP GET requests to a GoPro Camera.  FYI, I have gotten this to work for 3 different GoPro cameras, it is just the newer Hero 5 that is giving me problems.  It is probably something simple, but the client connection works and the HTTP requests work right after the wifi connections have been reset on the camera, but if the ESP8266 is reset after a first WiFi connection, it connects to the WiFi fine, but all HTTP requests return a -1 HTTP Code and the client fails to connect.

I'm using the Platformio extension with Visual Studio Code.

I've tried calling client.flush() and just about anything else I can think of. The only way to make the commands work again is to reset the WiFi connections on the camera. If I connect using my computer, I have no problem sending the commands from Google Chrome. I've tried using the regular ESP8266WiFi library and the ESP8266HTTPClient library as shown below.  Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

// Use WiFiclient class to create TCP connections
WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;

const char* ssid     = "GP25000830";
const char* password = "vault9291";

String wifi_ssid = "GP25000830";
String wifi_password = "vault9291"; 

const char* host = "10.5.5.9";
const int httpPort = 80;


String StartURL = "/gp/gpControl/command/shutter?p=1";


void Trigger() {
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  //Command for starting recording
  client.print(String("GET ") + StartURL + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "User-Agent: RCRemote\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  Serial.println("Triggering");
  delay(20);
  client.stop();
}


void Trigger_http() {
  http.begin("http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/command/shutter?p=1");
  int httpCode = http.Get();
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  String payload = http.getString();
  Serial.println(payload);
  http.end();
}


void setup() {
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  WiFi.disconnect();

  Serial.begin(115200);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  client.flush();
}


void loop() {
  Trigger();
  // Trigger_http();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?